# Styled component DefaultTheme Module federation [React]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-module-federation

I'm trying to separate UIkit from the main app. But I cannot expose and transpile the Default theme on the host correctly. How to receive pure JS objects neither than the Loadeble component?

Here is an example of DefaultTheme on remote:

```
    export const theme: DefaultTheme = {
    border: {
      card: '1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221)',
      cardLight: '1px solid rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.4)',
      scrollable: "1px solid $meeseeks.color['neutrals.200']", // check if it works
    },
```

webpack.config:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin');
const { FederatedTypesPlugin } = require('@module-federation/typescript');
const path = require('path');

const FederatedPluginConfig = {
    name: 'uikit',
    filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
    exposes: {
        './Button': './src/component/Button/Button',
        './Text': './src/component/Typography/Typography',
        './Theme':'./src/DefaultTheme',
    },
    shared: [
        {
            react: {
                singleton: true,
                requiredVersion: false,
            }},
        {
            'react-dom': {
                singleton: true,
                requiredVersion: false,
            },
        }
    ],
}
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index',
    mode: 'development',
    devServer: {
        static: {
            directory: './dist',
        },
        port: 4000,
    },
    output: {
        publicPath: 'auto',
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@Component': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/component'),
            '@Utils': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utils'),
            '@Types': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/types'),
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.tsx', '.ts', '.json'],
        modules: [
            'node_modules',
            'src',
        ],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx|ts?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-typescript'],
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new ModuleFederationPlugin(FederatedPluginConfig),
        new FederatedTypesPlugin({
            federationConfig:FederatedPluginConfig}),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './public/index.html',
        }),
    ],

};
```

Host webpack.config:

```
const FederatedPluginConfig = {
    name: 'host',
    remotes: {
        uikit: 'uikit@http://localhost:4000/remoteEntry.js',
    },
    filename: 'static/chunks/remoteEntry.js',
    shared: {},
};
```

And finally import:

```
const uikit = dynamic(  () =>  import('uikit/Theme'), {
  ssr: false
});
```

**Expected behavior**

Recieved

```
border: {
      card: '1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221)',
      cardLight: '1px solid rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.4)',
      scrollable: "1px solid $meeseeks.color['neutrals.200']", // check if it works
    }
```

**Actual behavior**

`LoadableComponent(props)`

Comment: have you tried `const uikit = await import('uikit/Theme');`? I think the dynamic function is specific to components.

Comment: Than its `module not found`